# Lenovo X1 Mini-PCI-Express WiFi Card

Tags: thinkpad, minipci

I'm having problems with my wifi card in my new X1. Is the bios whitelisted to specific mini-pci-e cards? I've read this on various other sites, but none of them mention the X1. If I buy a new one on newegg, will it work?

Comment: I believe the answer is 'yes, it's got a whitelist' but I'm not sure.  You should consult Lenovo directly (or pull the Hardware Maintenance Manual for this model) to verify FRU#s of models that will work.

Comment: Ah, good idea. It does have a whitelist, looks like I'll have to buy from ebay sellers in china unless I want to pay $100+.

Comment: That or hack the bios whitelist....if you dare....http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_unauthorized_MiniPCI_network_card

Comment: Help fight the BIOS whitelist, sign the [petition to Lenovo.](https://www.change.org/petitions/lenovo-release-an-unencumbered-version-of-the-bios)